# How to receive value of 'n' input boxes?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How to receive the input values of variable number of input boxes?
I searched a long time in Google but I'm not able to do it.

ParentComponent.html:

```html
<my-Input [interfaces]="interfaces"> {{ title }}</my-Input>
```

ParentComponent.ts:

```
interface single_input{
 title: string,
 get_value(event: string): void;
}
    
interfaces: single_input[] = [
 {
  title: "something",
  get_value(event){ console.log(event)}
 }
];
```

ChildComponent.html:

```html
<div *ngFor="let i of interfaces">
    <Input (keyup)="i.get_value($event.target.value)"> {{ title }}</Input>
</div>
```

To log this in the console works, but I just want to bind the input values to the given interface and give it back by eventemitter to the parent.

How to do this? Do I need a class for it?

I got it now.
But it looks like a workaround. is there a better solution than following code?

**Code-Update:**

ParentComponent.ts:

```
interface single_input{
 title: string;
 value: string;
}
    
interfaces: single_input[] = [
 {
  title: "something",
 }
];
```

ChildComponent.html:

```html
<div *ngFor="let i of interfaces">
    <Input (keyup)="i.value = $event.target.value"> {{ title }}</Input>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is far simpler than what you are trying to do. Angular have specific mechanism to achieve this goal, one of them being the decorators @Input and @Output. You are already using the @Input decorator to pass in the data to the child component, now you just need to use the @Output decorator to pass the data back to the parent. I recommend looking at the [docs](https://angular.io/api/core/Output) and this [example](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction) to have a better understanding on how this works. Below is an example for your use case.

**ChildComponent.html**

```html
<div *ngFor="let i of interfaces">
    <input (keyup)="onKeyUp(i, $event.target.value)"> {{ title }}</input>
</div>
```

**ChildComponent.ts**

```js
import { Component, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
@Component({ ... })
export class ChildComponent {
    ...
    @Input() interfaces;
    @Output() childValue: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
    //                                  ^ Use a proper datatype ^

    onKeyUp(source, value) {
        this.childValue.emit({
            source: source,
            value: value
        });
    }
    ...
}
```

**ParentComponent.html**

```html
<my-input [interfaces]="interfaces" (childValue)="onChildValueChange($event)"> {{ title }}</my-input>
```

**ParentComponent.ts**

```js
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
@Component({ ... })
export class ParentComponent {
    ...
    onChildValueChange(event) {
        // Do what you want with it
        const interface = this.interfaces.find(interface =>
            interface.title === event.source.title);
        console.log('[ParentComponent] Value from child component:', event);
        console.log('[ParentComponent] Changed interface:', interface);
        console.log('[ParentComponent] Changed value:', event.value);
    }
    ...
}
```

**Extra tip:** Just for completeness, an equally popular approach, would be using a service to contain the data, where the child changes the data on the service and the parent read from it.

Comment: and how do i know which inputbox has been triggered?
i have a input component which i want to use in different routes.
sometimes i need 2 input fields, sometimes 3 or more. thats why i tried to make it flexible by an interface.

Comment: I made an update to the answer to take into consideration your comment.

Comment: @David, think that you're working with arrays, it's unnecesary emit values. When you pass as `@Input` and array or an object you really pass the "a pointer to the array", any change in the elements of the array are saw by parent too. BTW, use [(ngModel)] of ReactiveForms, not keyUp, it's the correct way to do it in Angular

Comment: Actually, the `ngModel` directive with `ReactiveForms` is [deprecated](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName#use-with-ngmodel-is-deprecated) since version 6 and is to be removed in a later version. Regarding the fact that we could mutate the existing array, while it is true, I would not recommend it, immutability allows us to make much more reliable and easier to maintain applications. Also, we would still need to signal the parent component that a change was made.